Draw Chair package xymtex with brackets
I am drawing the cellulose structure using xymtex where is the connection error? This figure below is example
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{XyMcompd}(2200,1200)(250,-150){}{}
%%%outer picture environment
\put(673,-46){
\put(0,0){\chair{1Se==;2Se==OH ;3Se==OH;4Se==O\chairi{1==(yl)};6Se==\null\dimethylene{2==OH}{1Sa==(yl)}}}
\put(1030,552){\makebox(0,0){\upnobond{\SetTwoAtomx{O}{}}}}
}
\end{XyMcompd}
\end{document}



What do you mean by "where is the connection error"?

The xymtexpdf package seems to be very powerful. Alas, I never really used it. Therefore, I suggest the chemfig package as alternative:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\chemfig[cram width=2pt,atom style={scale=0.75}]{
    -[@{l}:10]
    ?[a]<[:-50](-[:170]HO)
    -[:10,,,,line width=2pt,line cap=round](-[:-50]OH)
    >[:-10](-[:130]O-[:190](?[a])-[:130]-[:50]OH)
    -[:10]O-[:-10]
    ?[c]<[:10](-[:230]-[:310]OH)
    -[:-10,,,,line width=2pt,line cap=round]O
    >[:50](-[:190](-[:50]OH)-[:170](?[c])-[:190]HO)
    -[:-10]O-[@{r}:10]
}
\polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},open xshift=-0.75em,close xshift=-0.5em,
    height=3em,depth=4.5em,indice=n]{l}{r}

\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thanks very muh help

@FabioLima The package you tried also looks very promising. But I have to admit that I never used it and therefore can't help with this package.
